# How do I be inclusive of Letters into?

Tags: java, parsing, comparator

> String
>   input="4,8,222cd,77,77A";

I sorted the values.for example, I sorted 3,4,5,6 consecutive values in the range [3-6].I have done consecutive numbers "[]" in this format but I couldn't make the letters. Sorted list should not be disrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example method to merge the letters at the end:

```
static List<String> mergeLetters(List<String> items){
    Map<String, List<String>> mergingCandidates = new HashMap<>();
    for (String s : items) {
        int length = s.length();
        if (length > 1 && Character.isLetter(s.charAt(length - 1))) {
            String key = s.substring(0, length - 1);
            String value = s.substring(length - 1);
            List<String> tmp = mergingCandidates.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new LinkedList<String>());
            tmp.add(value);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : mergingCandidates.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<String> characterList = entry.getValue();
        if (characterList.size() > 1) {
            boolean consecutive = true;
            Character[] characters = characterList.stream().map(s -> s.charAt(0)).toArray(Character[]::new);
            for (int i = 0; i < characters.length - 1; i++) {
                if (characters[i + 1] - characters[i] != 1) {
                    consecutive = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (consecutive) {
                int indexToBeReplaced = items.indexOf(key + characterList.get(0));
                String newValue = key + "[" + characterList.get(0)
                        + "-" + characterList.get(characterList.size() - 1) + "]";
                characterList.forEach(letter -> items.remove(key + letter));
                items.add(indexToBeReplaced, newValue);
            }
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Explanation:

- You find all the sequences that differ only on the last letter and make a Map out of them.
- You pick the Map entries that have 2 or more ending letters.
- You check if the letters are consecutive.
- If yes, remove them and add a new merged entry instead. Be careful to add the new entry at the same index.

The main method should sort the items, first merge the digits as you correctly do now, and then replace the letters that can be merged:

```
String input = "605,2A,401-2A,32C,21F,201A,605A,401-1A,200-2E,462A,462,583-58D,200,462-1A,583/58E,583-57D, 542,2B, 1, 542/2E, 801, 802, 803, 605B, 32D, 3, 603, 4, 6, 5, 60, 201C, 542/2D,40,20,2C,800,800-1,50,200-2C,21C,800A,200A,571-573L,51/2,470/1,51/1,571-573K,454-1,444-446,571-573M";
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(input.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
items.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
items.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> Integer.parseInt(o.split("\\D")[0])));
List<String> merged = mergeRanges(items);
List<String> mergeLetters = mergeLetters(merged);
System.out.println(("Result: " + mergeLetters));
```

The output for your input is:

```
Result: [1, 2[A-C], [3-6], 20, 21C, 21F, 32[C-D], 40, 50, 51/1, 51/2, 60, 200, 200-2C, 200-2E, 200A, 201A, 201C, 401-1A, 401-2A, 444-446, 454-1, 462, 462-1A, 462A, 470/1, 542, 542/2[D-E], 571-573[K-M], 583-57D, 583-58D, 583/58E, 603, 605, 605[A-B], 800, 800-1, 800A, [801-803]]
```

Comment: You use remove() on the old list for each value to be removed and addAll() to insert all the new merged entries that you make (i.e. 2[A-C], 571-573[K-M], etc). I updated the solution. Please check it.

Comment: The best solution is to sort at the beginning. You can replace your comparing logic with the following steps:
`items.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
 items.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> Integer.parseInt(o.split("\\D")[0])));`
First you sort using the natural order and the sort based on the integer value of the first digits. The split takes all the numbers until the first non-digit character.

Comment: Also, my solution put the merging candidates at the end of the list. Check the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is first to expand all the declarations in the input, then sort them, then to emit them again, while compacting ranges when you encounter successive items,.

1. Expand all declarations: 571-573K (if I understand correctly) would expand to the three items 571K, 572K, 573K. Most simple declarations just expand to themselves.
2. Sort: You need a sort function that is sensitive to both numbers and letters. It will probably have to break up the input string and compre the number part numerically, but the letter part alphabetically.
3. Emit: Walk the sorted list and emit each item; however, if the *next* item is adjacent to the current item, merge it with the current item instead. This will probably require that you create a temporary list of outputs, and delay the actual output until you've gone through the original list.